# how to cover parent view fully from a subview in ios?

Tags: ios7, uiview, uistoryboard

Im creating an ios app using story board. I want to add a subview over the current viewcontroller. the current view controller should be fully covered from that sub view. But my problem is when I add the subview it appear under the navigation bar. I set is as

`[self.view addSubview:mysubview];`

How do I fully cover my view from that sub view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to cover the complete navigation controller, you can try this instead:

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:mysubview];
```